# Call another modal when radio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 modal window, written in bootstrap. When I click in first modal on radio, I want to close this modal and then open another.

My html for first form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="overlay" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Can we help?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="callback">Callback</label>
            <input type="radio" id="callbackRadio">
            <label for="contactUs">Contact Us</label>
            <input type="radio" id="contactUsRadio">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
if($('#contactUsRadio').is('checked')){
      $('#overlay').modal('hide');
      $('#contactUsModal').modal('show');
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What does _it doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: Firstly, it must be: `$('#contactUsRadio').is(':checked')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to trigger an event (assuming you aren't, as you haven't pasted that in with your code)

```
$('#contactUsRadio').on('click', function() {
    if($('#contactUsRadio').is(':checked')) {
        $('#overlay').modal('hide');
        $('#contactUsModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```